# Resolving net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED at Ubuntu Server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, devops, puppeteer, digital-ocean

I'm running puppeteer scraper at Digital Ocean droplet.

- Server is **Ubuntu 18.04**
- **ufw** is enabled and **ssh**, **http**, **https** ports enabled.
- This scraper has been running by **pm2**

This is the current output and Code snip.

> 0|server   | 2019-12-23T09:09:27.266Z: [openPage] Error:
>   net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED at https://xxxx/xxxx

```
...
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     headless: false,
     args:["--no-sandbox", "--proxy-server=zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225"]
});
page = await browser.newPage()

// set random agent to page
await page.setUserAgent(agents[Math.floor(Math.random() * agents.length)])

await page.authenticate({
  username: process.env.USERNAME,
  password: process.env.PWD
})
....
```

plus `env` variables are working correctly. I checked this out by `console.log(process.env.USERNAME)`

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your proxy DOES support HTTPS/SSL if you'd like Puppeteer to scrape HTTPS content.

You can easily test if your proxy supports SSL with:

```
curl --proxy [ip]:[port] https://ipinfo.io/ip
```